# Composite versus square notation in functions

Tags: functions, notation

What is meaning of $f^2(x)$ ? There seems to be confusion in its interpretation.

Is $f^2(x)$ same as $(f(x))^2$ or $f\circ f$?

Answer (score 4):

It depends upon the context. It can be both. But if $f$ is a function from some set $S$ into $\mathbb R$, then it can only be $\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^2$. And if it is a function from a set $S$ into itself and if that set has no multiplication defined in it, then it can only mean $f\circ f$.

Comment: The  function is f(x) = (cx-d)/(dx-c) for x is a real number,  x i,s not equal to c/d c and d are fixed constants and c>d>0  . What is f^2(x) here and its domain,

Comment: My gues is that it will be $f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am not able to get a proper justification for it. Could you please help..

Comment: I cannot help you here, since I don't have access to the whole problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: The question is: the function f(x) = (cx-d)/(dx-c) for x is a real number, x is not equal to c/d. Here c and d are fixed constants and c>d>0. Find f^2(x), stating clearly the domain. Hence state the range of f^2(x).Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It can be both, but unless you are in a context where function iteration makes sense, it is more likely to be the square.

---

The confusion is a little worse with the exponent $-1$: $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is more likely to be the arc sine than the cosecant. The functional inverse is not so exotic.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret it as $(f(x))^2$ whenever it makes sense. If $f(x)$ is not defined (for example, if it is a vector), then I would understand $f\circ f$

Anyway, I would make sure the meaning is consistent throughout my work, never mixing them.

In topics such as linear algebra, I will always mean $f \circ f$ If I am talking about calculus, I would expect you to understand $(f(x))^2$